# Installation query

Tags: system-installation

I have download Xubuntu 14.04 and unzipped it to a folder on my desktop containing 9 folders

What do I click on next to proceed with an installation?

Please advise as I cannot find an exe file.

TIA

Ron

Comment: The ubuntu .iso is not a zip file  and that is not how you install ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Don't unzip it. You have to burn it to some sort of installation media. (DVD, CD, USB)

I recommend using [ISO to USB](http://www.isotousb.com/), but you can also right-click on the ISO file and burn it to a DVD.

Reply here if you need help booting into the installation media, or anything else.